# Kafka Connect Parallelism and Multi threading

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Had a question regarding parallelism and multi threading on kafka connect cluster. I am writing a simple kafka source connector to consume files and send it to a kafka cluster (source connector). However if I run the connector and put maxTasks as a number greater than 1 and if it runs on multiple nodes or machines I want only one thread=task to access the file. One thread per file, but there can be n files. Each task should consume only file at a time and that file should be locked for other threads or tasks for the entire connect cluster. How to go about this ? Concurrency in java is limited to a single jvm. The inbound files come in S3 or blob storage. So only those can be passed as properties of tasks. Not file names \ regexes. Any pointers for parallelism would be appreciated.

Comment: There already exists an S3 source connector, but you'll need an external way to lock file readers per file

Comment: How does that confluent S3 source connector achieve this parallelism ? Or for that matter any other connector ? Are you saying external way as in some kind of data store \ topic where we store this and then enable this check ? Wish there was some method provided in connect api for this.

Comment: I'm not sure, I've really only used Spark for distributed S3 reads, and never really looked into how it prevents reading the same file

Comment: @OneCricketeer Most of the connectors out there use Kafka itself as the store I think. Looks like they store the current processing state in some kafka topic and use that as the monitor. Way more complex than I thought it is.

Comment: Yes, source connectors use the offsets topic for some state management, but I dont know if that also acts as a locking mechanism. Probably it writes some metadata back to the filesystem